# How to target both key and value to replace characters in an array

Tags: php, associative-array

I am trying to target both keys and values in an associative array to remove double quote strings. I am passing into a php controller a string via JSON.stringify like this:

```
"searchFilterType":"inside","searchFilterField":"okay","searchFilterGeoDistance":"27","searchFilterZip":"2","keyword":"test"
```

I assign that to a variable `$string;`

I use the following to break it apart into an array:

```
$sExplode = explode(',', $string);
$searchFilters = [];
```

Which gives me

```
[0] => "searchFilterType":"inside"
[1] => "searchFilterField":"okay"
[2] => "searchFilterGeoDistance":"25"
[3] => "searchFilterZip":""
[4] => "keyword":"test"
```

I then break that into an associative array using this:

```
foreach ($sExplode as $v) {
        $v = explode(":",$v);
        $searchFilters[$v[0]] = $v[1];
}
```

Which gives me:

```
["searchFilterType"] => "inside"
["searchFilterField"] => "okay"
["searchFilterGeoDistance"] => "27"
["searchFilterZip"] => "2"
["keyword"] => "test"
```

I then remove the strings from the values using this:

```
$searchFilters = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $searchFilters);
```

Giving me:

```
["searchFilterType"] => inside
["searchFilterField"] => okay
["searchFilterGeoDistance"] => 27
["searchFilterZip"] => 2
["keyword"] => test
```

But I still need to remove the string in the array keys. My main goal I am reaching to is an end result of:

```
[searchFilterType] => inside
[searchFilterField] => okay
[searchFilterGeoDistance] => 27
[searchFilterZip] => 2
[keyword] => test
```

Is there an easier solution that these multiple steps?

Comment: why not just `json_decode` it?

Comment: Why not manually add the opening/closing bracket on the JSON literal and then use `json_decode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$string` is JSON, the simplest thing to do is use `json_decode`.

```
$result = json_decode($string, true);
```

If `$string` is a JSON fragment like you've shown in the question, the simplest thing to do is still probably `json_decode`. You'd just need to add the brackets to complete it before it could be decoded.

```
$data = json_decode('{'.$string.'}', true);
```

Comment: i have posted from the cell phone so attached just link.

Comment: @Dolar If you know of a helpful link, but aren't able to write a complete answer at the time, you can always post it in a comment.

Comment: i will consider your suggestion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go down the JSON route, this just does the `explode()` in the same way and then goes through the result array and processes it as though it's a delimited string (using `str_getcsv()`) with `:` as the separator and allowing it to remove the quotes.

Finally use `array_column()` to combine the key and the value into an associative array...

```
$string = '"searchFilterType":"inside","searchFilterField":"okay","searchFilterGeoDistance":"27","searchFilterZip":"2","keyword":"test"';
$sExplode = explode(',', $string);
$map = array_map(function ( $value ) { return str_getcsv($value, ":", '"'); }, $sExplode);

$out = array_column($map, 1, 0);
print_r($out);
```

gives..

```
Array
(
    [searchFilterType] => inside
    [searchFilterField] => okay
    [searchFilterGeoDistance] => 27
    [searchFilterZip] => 2
    [keyword] => test
)
```